# Where to find Leszek Demkowicz's finite element codes or alternatives?

Tags: finite-element

I know that long back Dr. Leszek Demkowicz finite elements codes(1Dhp,2Dhp,3Dhp) were available in his website. I'm finding it difficult to locate it now. Is there any alternatives available to these codes in FORTRAN(77/90) only.

Comment: Hi @renormaizedQuanta.  I'm curious... What is so special about these codes that you seek them out?

Comment: @Paul They illustrate the ideas presented in his book.

Comment: @paul Specialty is that I can program in only FORTRAN. I know about Deal.II and Hermes but they are all written in C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prof. Demkowicz has asked me to post the following reply (I have slightly edited it so that fits better with the site's format):

> 1. 1D and 2D codes come with [the first volume of my book](http://books.google.com/books/about/Computing_with_hp_ADAPTIVE_FINITE_ELEMEN.html?id=Xc3yGiekgEUC). I can E-mail both codes following a [personal request](http://www.ices.utexas.edu/people/80/) but it is impossible to read them w/o my book...
> 2. The (old) 3D code has been described in [the second volume of our books](http://books.google.com/books/about/Computing_with_hp_ADAPTIVE_FINITE_ELEMEN.html?id=03B-5AH7D10C). It is still in use by my colleagues in Cracow including Dr. Rachowicz. Please  [contact him directly](https://www.ices.utexas.edu/people/59/) for a working copy of that code. Again, it is impossible to use that code w/o reading the book first.
> 3. We have a new, very powerful 3Dhp code (developed by current students) that it is accessible to my collaborators. Interested parties should get in touch with me directly...

Comment: Thanks, Juan I appreciate your help. I'll contact Prof. Demkowicz.

Answer (score 2):

I think the code was also distributed with his books. But you may just want to write him an email :-)

Comment: Thanks Dr. Wolfgang, do you know any alternative to these codes in FORTRAN. I know about your wonderful Deal.II framework, but I don't know C++.

Comment: This may be your opportunity to learn C++ :-) Other than that, you may want to look at PHAML: http://math.nist.gov/phaml/

Answer (score 2):

Dr. Demkowicz's codes are pretty unique, so you aren't going to find a complete alternative, in any language.

If you are just looking for a Fortran code, you can get [FEAPpv](http://www.ce.berkeley.edu/projects/feap/feappv/)

I put this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_element_software_packages) together a long time ago  and someone liste [Elmer](http://www.csc.fi/english/pages/elmer).  I have no experience using it.

Answer (score 0):

I have these codes on my computer (files: tar1d.tgz, tar2d.tgz, and tar3d.tgz). I downloaded them from his website a year ago, or so.  I just like collecting codes, I'm also looking for some (if someone could help me find Orszag's CENTIKUBE it would be great).

You may contact me and I'll forward them to you.

Comment: Johntra, scicomp is a wiki-style question and answer site, not a discussion board (feel free to use either meta or chat for requests and statements like this).  Please either provide direct URL references or code explicitly.

Comment: Sorry for that, I got carried away in my  wish to help out. If others think like this too, I will just erase my post. Unfortunately I was unable to recover the link where I downloaded the codes.

Comment: It's fine, we try to keep the community as open as possible while maintaining the minimum number of hard rules.  We're all in this together, and I appreciate your enthusiasm!